# Set cell owner when loaded from Xib

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a created custom table view cell class named `CustomCell` which inherits from `UITableViewCell`.

I have also created xib file for the cell named `CustomCell.xib`.
In the xib file, I have specified custom class to be the `CustomCell`,
and also set the file's owner to be `CustomCell` class.

Now, I have connected the some button `touchUpInside` to be handled in the file's owner which is `CustomCell`.

I load the cell with the following code in my table view controller:

```
NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
  loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];

cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex: 0];
```

As you can see, the loaded cell does not have owner (`owner:nil` parameter), 
and the problem is that I need the owner to be set to cell itself.

How can I set the owner for the `cell` explicitly?

Is there some other way to load xib and to make that cell instance become owner to itself?

Comment: I'm just guessing, but would it work to set `owner:self` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your cell and your button are both in the same nib, you can just make the connection between them inside the nib.

The "file's owner" proxy is just there to help you make a connection to an object that isn't in the nib. "File's owner" is just a proxy for the owner of this nib at runtime.

But since the two objects you wish to connect are both inside the nib already, you can just make that connection directly.

Comment: I have managed to solve this myself by removing File's owner from the xib and when creating new connections they are targeting my CustomCell class.

I am curious, is there a possibility to target some actions and/or outlets to my CustomClass and some other to the File's Owner? How is this done in XCode?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I am a newbie and some simple tasks are not so obvious in XCode.